# Python/Django: Filter objects by Concat() and order by the same concatenation

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-models

In my Python/Django API project I need to get a quesryset from a model filtered by a concatenated combination of two fields and order by the same concatenation. However I only know to filter by one field like shown below.

Requirement: TimeTable has two fields "date" and "time". I need to list data where the combination of both these fields are greater than current date time.

Code:

```
current_time = datetime.now()

timetable = TimeTable.objects.filter(user=user_id, date__gte=current_time.date()).order_by(Concat('date','time'))
```

MySQL equivalent of the scenario:

```
SELECT * FROM time_table where concat(date,' ',time)>='2020-03-24 12:00:00' and user=user_id order by concat(date,' ',time) ASC
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just provide multiple fields in the [**`order_by(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) function as,

```
TimeTable.objects.filter(date__gte='2020-04-02').order_by('date','time')
```

**Note:** You don't have to concatinate those values (in your case).

---

### Update

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat, Cast
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, CharField, Value
from datetime import datetime

date_time_expr = Cast(Concat('date', Value(' '), 'time', output_field=CharField()), output_field=DateTimeField())

TimeTable.objects.annotate(date_time=date_time_expr).filter(date_time__gte=datetime.now()).order_by('date_time')
```

Comment: This is what I've already done but not what I need to do. Both date and time fields together must be greater than or equal to '2020-04-02 12:00:00'. filter(date__gte='2020-04-02', time__gte='12:00:00') even does not do the intended job.

Comment: Can I ask why didn't you use the **`DateTimeField`** in the first place?

Comment: IMHO, use `DateTimeField`

Comment: That would be easier but the requirement is to store date and time separately.